# How does Pulsar store messages of multiple topics in ledgers?

Tags: apache-pulsar

Pulsar uses bookkeeper as the backend storage, and store topic metadata in `managed-ledgers/$namespace/persistent` zookeeper path.

On the bookkeeper side, the data is stored under `/data/bookkeeper/ledgers/current` path. The log file name does not reflect relationship with topic partitions. I am wondering how BookKeeper stores messages of multiple topics, and how messages are looked up and delivered to consumers.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1073706218 Jul 31 06:56 aa2d.log 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1073705854 Jul 31 06:56 aa2e.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1073722807 Jul 31 06:57 aa2f.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Each topic has a znode under managed-ledgers/$namespace/persistent, which contains the list of bookkeeper ledgers which contain the backlog for that topic.

Comment: thanks for the reply!  is it possible that a ledger contains entries from multiple topics?

Comment: No, a ledger will only contain entries from a single topic.